# Can't RET in emacs Interactive-Haskell-mode

Tags: haskell, emacs, haskell-mode

I have emacs 24.4, and have installed the latest Haskell platform (10.11) for mac. I have installed `haskell-mode` through emacs `package-install`, and followed the Haskell-mode tutorial (https://github.com/serras/emacs-haskell-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial.md#haskell-mode). I created a test file thereafter; however, when I load the interpreter (`C-c C-l`), I don't receive any error messages, but I am unable to `RET` anything. I tried looking online for a solution, but couldn't find any. Any advice would be appreciated.

Ah, I forgot to mention: running `ghci` through terminal works fine, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Do you have `(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'inf-haskell-mode)` in your emacs init file ?

Comment: Are you using `spacemacs` (or evil) ? If so,  you should read https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/3271

Comment: @Sibi - Ah, I don't have that line in my init file. I will try that once I get a chance to go back on my laptop. PierreR - I am not using spacemacs (nor evil, I think).

Comment: Hello again, I have added the line you have suggested above into my init file; I am still unable to [RET] anything.

Comment: @ams034 What is the name of your file ?

Comment: @Sibi I just created a filename called test.hs. Or, did you mean my init file? Could it possibly be because I have both `inf-haskell-mode` and `interactive-haskell-mode` in my init (.emacs) file? Thanks for your help once again.